# "Resetting" the "Head" pointer of an linked list

Tags: c

I have to reuse this piece of code in the same function but it wont work because the res1->nextPtr is already at the end of the linked list. Is there a way to reset it to the "Head" of the linked list?

```
do
{
    res1 = res1->nextPtr;
}while(res1 != NULL);
```

Comment: Save the head before traversing. If you can't do this and it's a doubly linked list, simply traverse back.

Comment: @Zeta How will I save the head? As which data type? This is not a doubly linked list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
LIST *head = res1;
LIST *list = head;
while (list) {
  //do something
  list = list->nextPtr;
};

list= head;
//again traverse over list
```

if your res1 is NULL your do-while will segfault.